# With JEasyUI how to get a real JavaScript Date from DateTimeBox and TimeSpinner?

Tags: javascript, datetime, datepicker, datetimepicker, jquery-easyui

Simple HTML code,

```
<div class="easyui-datebox" style="width:250px;height:30px;"></div>
<div class="easyui-calendar" style="width:250px;height:250px;"></div>
<div class="easyui-timespinner" style="width:250px;height:30px;"></div>
<div class="easyui-datetimebox" style="width:250px;height:30px;"></div>
```

Callback functions on them, for when they change,

```
function setText(raw, parser) {
    var date = '';
    if(parser) {
    try{
        date = parser(raw);
    }
    catch(e) {
        date = e;
    }
  }

    $('.easyui-textbox').textbox(
    'setText',
      'Raw: ' + raw + ', Parsed: ' + date + '\n' + $('.easyui-textbox').textbox('getText'));
}

$('.easyui-datebox').datebox({
    onChange: function(newVal) {
    setText(newVal, $.fn.datebox.defaults.parser);
    }
});

$('.easyui-timespinner').timespinner({
    onChange: function(newVal) {
    setText(newVal, $.fn.timespinner.defaults.parser);
    }
});

$('.easyui-datetimebox').datetimebox({
    onChange: function(newVal) {
    setText(newVal, $.fn.datetimebox.defaults.parser);
  }
});

$('.easyui-calendar').calendar({
    onChange: function(newVal) {
    setText(newVal);
    }
});
```

With `datebox`, its `$.fn.datebox.defaults.parser` works as expected, with `calendar`, it does the work for you, and it's already a date in the callback, as well as in its `current` property.

But with both `datetimebox`, and `timespinner`, we get an obscure error in `jquery.easyui.min.js`,

```
TypeError: $.data(...) is undefined
```

The documentation isn't great here, and I can't find an uncompressed version of `EasyUI` to get a handle on exactly what's going wrong in the parser.

So, as the title goes, how do I get the real date from EasyUI's `DateTimeBox`, and `TimeSpinner`, just like I'm able to get with `Calendar` and `DateBox`?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's still compressed, when you look at the source of both `jquery.easyui.min.js`, you'll see what the problem is.  For whatever reason (I'm going to assume it's a bug), the parsers for both `DateTimeBox` and `TimeSpinner` use the code `$(this)`, which in proper context is fine, but calling the function in the "static" way like `$.fn.datetimebox.defaults.parser(...)`, `this` in this context is the *wrong* `this`, it's a generic `Javascript` object, not the `HTML DOM` object that it's expecting.

```
var _bd1=$(this).datetimebox("spinner").timespinner("options").separator;
```

and

```
var opts=$(this).timespinner("options");
```

are the offending lines.

To get around this, you need to use Javascript's `call` method accessor, which enables you to set the context for the called function.

So, instead of 
    $.fn.datetimebox.defaults.parser(newVal)

```
$.fn.datetimebox.defaults.parser.call(this, newVal)
```

And instead of
    $.fn.timespinner.defaults.parser(newVal)

```
$.fn.timespinner.defaults.parser.call(this, newVal)
```

This way, when the internal function accesses `this`, they're using the `this` you passed to them.

Updated JSFiddle example with those changes in,

https://jsfiddle.net/7pm89dp7/1/

Now, to me this still seems cumbersome, and my gut tells me there must be another and better way to do this, but I certainly can't find one!